# Get all attribute names of Core Data entity; Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

Is there a more efficient way to retrieve all the names/titles of attributes of a NSManagedObject than this:

```
func getAllAttributeTitles(_ myStatSheet:StatSheet) -> Array<String> {

    let dictAttributes = myStatSheet.entity.attributesByName
    var arrAttributeTitles:Array<String> = []

    for (key, _) in dictAttributes {
        arrAttributeTitles.append(key)
    }

    return arrAttributeTitles
}
```

Comment: That’s literally the intended way to do it. Are you finding that it’s inefficient in some way? Slow?

Comment: No, just wasn't sure if there was a different way to do it that I might of missed. I had to sleuth through the docs to figure it out so just wanted to check. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned, what you've got is the right way to do it. There are other ways but I wasn't at a Mac earlier and couldn't try them out.

A more "Swift-y" way to get the array would be something like

```
let arrAttributeTitles = myStatSheet.entity.attributesByName.enumerated().map { $0.element.key }
```

This won't be any more efficient, since it's really doing the same things, but it might be more what you were thinking of when you asked. It's still getting `attributesByName` and iterating over the result to get strings naming the attributes.

It might be worth noting that the argument type on your method could be `NSManagedObject` instead of `StatSheet`, since the code will work for any managed object of any entity type.

Comment: Thanks, that's really what I was asking, the reduction of lines of code.

Comment: Which code would you prefer in your code base, the more Swifty or the more verbose?

Comment: If I was writing it I’d write the Swifty version. If someone else on the project wrote your version I wouldn’t think it needed changing.